# TYPO3 won't update front-end page after external TypoScript modification

Tags: typo3

I am trying to edit a `.ts` file through the `Quixplorer`.

I click on edit, add the link and hit save. But it does not get updated on the actual page.

When I click a preview of the file within the `Quixplorer` i can see my change but it just won't show on the homepage...

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried to clear the cache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While editing `*.ts` files it is always required to clear whole cache from the backend, to take changes into account.

Also make sure, that you're modifying correct file. The often mistake is editing files which aren't included to the DB TS template. You can verify that with the `Template` module (after cache clearing).